# android: Replace fragment container inside a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--I use this include as container with the FrameLayout below-->
<!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.improvemybrand.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

and the problem is simple:

When I try to replace the container FrameLayout from my Coordinator, it does not work, it shows the new fragment but also keeps the old one, in my simple example, the TextView with Hello world will remains.

To replace, I'm using the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `TextView` is not a `Fragment`'s `View`, so it's not going to be affected by a `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: edit: @MikeM. should I wrap the TextView inside a fragment and choose the fragment to be replaced?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but `FragmentTransaction`s only handle `Fragment`s and their `View`s. If you want, you can make the `TextView` another `Fragment`'s `View`, or part of it, then the transaction will replace it accordingly. Or you could just remove it, or otherwise hide it, yourself, if it doesn't need to be part of a `Fragment`.

Comment: @MikeM. I think I understood... I have to remove the TextView from the XML and If I really want that, I have to add programmatically inside the onCreate and then the FragmentTransaction will be adding fragments inside my container. I will make some tests and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I should mention that any `Fragment` you want to replace/remove must be loaded dynamically - i.e., _not_ defined as a `<fragment>` element in your layout XML - but it sounds like that's your plan anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. yes, thank you, it worked! The main fragment is being loaded at runtime as well the others. Can't give you points without an answer :(

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a duplicate, but I can't find one that is about this same issue, and has a correct answer. Gimme a little bit, and I'll make an answer from our comments when I get a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FragmentTransaction`s deal only with `Fragment`s and their `View`s. The `TextView` you've defined in your layout is not (part of) a `Fragment`'s `View`, so it will not be affected by a `FragmentTransaction`, and the `Fragment` in your snippet will just be added on top of it.

You have a few options. You could hide or remove the `TextView` yourself when performing the transaction. This might be preferable, if that simple `TextView` is all you need initially, and sticking it in a `Fragment` could be overkill. You could also simply set an opaque background on the `Fragment`'s layout, which will effectively hide the `TextView`.

The probably best option, however, is to put the `TextView` in a layout for another `Fragment` which is loaded at startup. Subsequent transactions will then replace/remove it as you're expecting. Do note that any `Fragment` you wish to replace/remove at runtime must be loaded dynamically in your code. That is, they cannot be defined in `<fragment>` elements in your `Activity`'s layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should move TextView into Fragment's layout.

like this.

fragment_hello_world.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

HelloWorldFragment

```
public class HelloWorldFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_world, container, false);;
    }

}
```